# Desplazamiento de tipo booleano

Tags: php

Buenas días tengo el siguiente error cuando trato de ingresar al login y pongo mal el correo me aparece esta siguiente advertencia.

> Advertencia : tratando de acceder al desplazamiento de la matriz en el
> valor de tipo bool en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\avaluos-avance8\controladores\formulario.controlador.php
> en la línea 83

```
static public function ctrIngreso(){


    if (
        isset($_POST["loginEmail"]) 
    ) {
        $tabla = "perito";
        $item = "email";
        $valor = $_POST["loginEmail"];

        $respuesta = ModeloFormularios::mdlSeleccionarRegistrosdePerito($tabla, $item, $valor);

        if($respuesta["email"] == $_POST["loginEmail"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["loginPassword"]){

            $_SESSION["validarIngreso"] = "ok";
            echo '<script>

            if ( window.history.replaceState ) {

                window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );

            }

            window.location = "user-form.php?ruta=avaluos";

            </script>';
    }else{

        echo '<script>

        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {

            window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );

        }

        </script>';

        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error al ingresar al sistema, el email o la contraseña no coinciden</div>';
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `83` en tu código?

Comment: cual es el archivo `formulario.controlador.php`